# Boostrap vue - Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "state". Expected Boolean

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to insert the bootstrap vue validation, but it gives an error in the props :state, saying that the expected value is a boolean and I can't understand why.

I'll put the part of the codes referring

```
...
<b-form class="registerForm__form" @submit.prevent="checkFields">
   <b-form-group
        id="input-group-name"
        label-for="input-name"
      >
        <b-form-input
          id="input-name"
          data-input="name"
          type="text"
          v-model="form.name"
          placeholder=Nome
          :state="validation"
          maxlength="255"
          required
        >
        </b-form-input>

        <b-form-invalid-feedback :state="validation">
          Your user ID must be 5-12 characters long.
        </b-form-invalid-feedback>
        <b-form-valid-feedback :state="validation">
          Looks Good.
        </b-form-valid-feedback>
   </b-form-group>
...
</b-form>
...
 data(){
    return{
      form: {
        cpf: null,
        name: null,
        email: null,
        phone: null,
        city: null,
        select: null,
        terms: null
      },
    }
  },
  methods: {
    validation() {
      return this.form.name.length > 4 && this.form.name.length < 13
    },
  }
...
```

Utlizando vue2 e bootstrap vue 2.22.0

Answer (score 0):

`validation` is a function, while boolean value is expected. In this case the correct way to use it is `:state="validation()"`

Since `validation` method accepts no arguments and there are no reasons for it to be called on each render, it should be a computed instead:

```
  computed: {
    validation() { ...
```